# Varnish script for warming cache

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I am using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget --output-document=/dev/null --header='Cache-Control: no-cache' --tries=1 --quiet --base=http://example.com --input-file=/path/to/urls.txt
```

which is calling some urls I want to warm in Varnish from a txt file.

For this to work I added in

> Varnish vcl

this code:

```
acl warmuper_ip {
    "10.20.30.40";
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # the script varnish-cache-warmup.sh must always refresh the cache
    if (client.ip ~ warmuper_ip && req.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache") {
        set req.hash_always_miss = true;
    }
}
```

My question is, although this is working, every time I use this is it clearing cache and then add my urls? Because I am newbie and I don't want to clear Varnish every time I run this script. I just want to cache my links without affection previous cached links.

Answer (score 0):

`$req.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache"` I don't think the content you retrieve from the backend get cached.
The content is simply being fetched and delivered, but it won't be stored in cache.

Comment: What should I use there? As far I checked with my urls, it seems that after the cron runs content is cached in Varnish

Comment: If you can cache the content, just remove that header

Comment: You mean to leave this only: `(client.ip ~ warmuper_ip && req.http.Cache-Control)` ?

Comment: This will be more than enough  (client.ip ~ warmuper_ip)

Comment: Every time I run this script with cron Varnish is cleared? Because I don't want to clear Varnish.Just to add this links in cache

Comment: No, it's not. Just remove the no-cache header and it will work